How to display items from a List even when some of those items have a null value using LINQ?
I'm trying to write a LINQ query to show addresses that are related to users.
But I'd like to show addresses that reference invalid users as well. In this case, the fields related to the user should be set as null.
Glossary: "Invalid user": not found in the users list.
Here is my code:
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var users = GetUsers();
            var addresses = GetAddresses();

            var result = from address in addresses
                         from user in users
                         where user.Id == address.UserId
                         select new
                         {
                             address.Street,
                             address.Zipcode,
                             Id = address.UserId,
                             Name = user.Name,
                             Email = user.Email,
                         };
            foreach(var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Street: {item.Street}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Zipcode: {item.Zipcode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Email: {item.Email}");
            }
        }

        static List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            const string usersData = "[{\"id\":\"e135e5f9-64ed-4176-a543-ac7f09c15600\",\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"email\":\"johndoe@email.com\"},{\"id\":\"d906db73-f711-4498-88b9-dc2d9d54ece5\",\"name\":\"James Scott\",\"email\":\"jamesscott@email.com\"}]";

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<User>>(usersData, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true })!;
        }

        static List<Address> GetAddresses()
        {
            const string addressData = "[{\"street\":\"206 Hazel St\",\"zipcode\":\"16853\",\"city\":\"Milesburg\",\"state\":\"PA\", \"country\": \"USA\",\"userId\":\"e135e5f9-64ed-4176-a543-ac7f09c15600\"},{\"street\":\"208 Mill St\",\"zipcode\":\"16853\",\"city\":\"Milesburg\",\"state\":\"PA\", \"country\": \"USA\",\"userId\":\"d906db73-f711-4498-88b9-dc2d9d54ece5\"},{\"street\":\"100 Turnpike St\",\"zipcode\":\"16853\",\"city\":\"Milesburg\",\"state\":\"PA\", \"country\": \"USA\",\"userId\":\"b84b9728-b657-4db9-8af7-45789983d931\"}]";

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Address>>(addressData, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true })!;
        }
    }

    internal class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    }

    internal class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    
}

With the code above, addresses related to invalid users are ignored.
I was expecting to receive a List like so:
  "Street": "206 Hazel St"
  "Zipcode": "16853",
  "Id": "e135e5f9-64ed-4176-a543-ac7f09c15600",
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Email": "johndoe@email.com"
},
{
  "Street": "208 Mill St"
  "Zipcode": "16853",
  "Id": "d906db73-f711-4498-88b9-dc2d9d54ece5",
  "Name": "James Scott",
  "Email": "jamesscott@email.com"
},
{
  "Street": "100 Turnpike St"
  "Zipcode": "16853",
  "Id": null,
  "Name": null,
  "Email": null
}]


To start with, let's change your query to use a join:
var result =
    from address in addresses
    join user in users on address.UserId equals user.Id
    select new
    {
        address.Street,
        address.Zipcode,
        Id = address.UserId,
        Name = user.Name,
        Email = user.Email,
    };

And I replaced address.UserId with user.Id.
Now we can change this to a group join:
var result =
    from address in addresses
    join user in users on address.UserId equals user.Id into grouped_users
    let maybe_single_user = grouped_users.SingleOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        address.Street,
        address.Zipcode,
        Id = maybe_single_user?.Id,
        Name = maybe_single_user?.Name,
        Email = maybe_single_user?.Email,
    };

There the grouped_users.SingleOrDefault() gets us the user or a null. It's then a matter of using the Elvis operator to propogate the null into the output.
Let's craft the output rather that dumping a series of Console.WriteLine statements.
var outputs =
    result
        .Select(item =>
            String
                .Join(
                    Environment.NewLine,
                    new[]
                    {
                        $"Street: {item.Street}",
                        $"Zipcode: {item.Zipcode}",
                        $"Id: {item.Id}",
                        $"Name: {item.Name}",
                        $"Email: {item.Email}",
                    }));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, outputs));

And that gives us:
Street: 206 Hazel St
Zipcode: 16853
Id: e135e5f9-64ed-4176-a543-ac7f09c15600
Name: John Doe
Email: johndoe@email.com

Street: 208 Mill St
Zipcode: 16853
Id: d906db73-f711-4498-88b9-dc2d9d54ece5
Name: James Scott
Email: jamesscott@email.com

Street: 100 Turnpike St
Zipcode: 16853
Id:
Name:
Email: 


Thank you bro. It solved my problem! I've never heard of those joins. I'm going to read more about it.
